# x86 how the hardware detects and set overflow register flag

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm currently learning assembly programming by following the book "Assembly Language for x86 processor 7th Edition".

In the book, the author tried to explain how the `overflow register flag` is set

[image]

There are two sentences in this paragraph that I'm unsure of.

1. the value that carries out the highest bit position is exclusive ORed with the carry into the high bit of the result
2. 1 XOR 0 produces OF = 1

Additional question on point 2: I know how `XOR` works, but I'm not sure which bit is the `1` and `0` in `1 XOR 0` are referring to.

How does this actually work? I'm very confused by the wording used by the author.

Comment: See [Understanding Carry vs. Overflow conditions/flags for signed vs. unsigned.](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) which explains things in detail.  See also the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for other useful links.

Answer (score 3):

It says to XOR the carry into the highest bit with the carry out of the highest bit, the carry out is already given (1, in its own box), and the carry in is quite obviously zero. To make it even more obvious, the carry into the highest bit is the carry out of the bottom 7 bits:

[image: carry7]

Since the first addend is zero, it's obvious that there can be no carry. In the original problem that means there is no carry into the highest bit.

Answer (score 1):

The two operands are 
first operand:  10000000 and 
second operand: 11111110
-->The highest bit of the first operand is  1 (leftmost)
-->The highest bit of the second operand is 1 (leftmost)
Now, if we add these two bits
1+1 = 0 carry 1 (binary addition)
So, we got 0 as the sum and 1 as the carry out (carry out of the highest bit).
Now, lets find the "carry into the highest bit(8th bit)".
"carry in" is generated from the sum of all the previous bits (last 7 bits as the operand has 8 bits). If we keep adding first seven bits of both operands, there is no incoming carry to the 8th bit, so its 0.

Finally,
carry out of the highest bit = 1
carry into the highest bit   = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1